# Property 'then' does not exist on function bound via bindActionCreators

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I have followed the official Redux guide to create my thunk action creator, so that I can use the bound actions in my react component. However, my component does not recognize that the function returns a promise so it I can't use `then`, which also means I do not have access to the return value of function.

Here is my action creator code sample:

```
// Temp State for now, not important
type IAppState = any;

// Just a sample response object
interface ISampleThunkResponse {
  text: string;
  active: boolean;
}

// Thunk action
export function sampleThunk(
  text: string
): ThunkAction<Promise<ISampleThunkResponse>, IAppState, null, Action<string>> {
  return async (dispatch, getState): Promise<ISampleThunkResponse> => {
    const apiResponse = await Promise.resolve({ text, active: true });
    dispatch({ payload: apiResponse, type: 'SOME_TYPE' });
    return apiResponse;
  };
}
```

My Component looks something like this:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { sampleThunk } from './sampleThunk';
import * as React from 'react';

export interface ISampleCompProps {
  sampleThunkConnect?: typeof sampleThunk;
}

export function SampleComp(props: ISampleCompProps) {
  const {
    sampleThunkConnect
  } = props;

  function handleClick() {
    // HERE IS THE ERROR
    // Property 'then' does not exist on type 'ThunkAction<Promise<ISampleThunkResponse>, any, null, Action<string>>'.
    sampleThunkConnect('SAMPLE TEXT').then(value => console.log(value));
  }
  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>Whatever...</div>
  );
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      sampleThunkConnect: sampleThunk,
    },
    dispatch
  );
}

export default connect<(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SampleComp);
```

EDIT:

Ok, so I've read the info provided by Mark, and I got it to work, flawlessly! My `sampleThunk` stayed the same, so no changes needed there. Here is my new component code:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { sampleThunk } from './sampleThunk';
import * as React from 'react';
import { InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps } from 'react-redux';

// Typing
type ConnectedProps<T> = T extends InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<infer Props, infer _>
      ? Props
      : never;

type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

export interface ISampleCompOwnProps {
  uuid: string;
}

type ISampleCompProps = ISampleCompOwnProps & PropsFromRedux;

// Temp State for now, not important
type IAppState = any;

// Redux Connect
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  sampleThunkConnect: sampleThunk,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: IAppState) => ({
  someStateKey: state.someStateKey,
});

const connector = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
);

// tslint:disable-next-line function-name
export function SampleComp(props: ISampleCompProps) {
  const {
    sampleThunkConnect
  } = props;

  function handleClick() {
    // Everything is working now!
    sampleThunkConnect('SAMPLE TEXT').then(value => console.log(value));
  }
  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>Whatever...</div>
  );
}

export default connector(SampleComp);
```

The key parts are, which I wished were also provided in the redux documentation, is having the `ConnectedProps` type, to be able to wrap your `connector`.

I have also transformed the functional `mapDispatchToProps` to an object version, but this doesn't really change anything as far as typing goes.

The bigger change was having to move my connect call into a variable in order to have it available for my `ConnectedProps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ISampleCompProps` declaration for `sampleThunkConnect` is wrong.

There's a difference in types between how the thunk action creator + thunk function are defined, and the type of the bound prop passed in to your component.

Ultimately, `this.props.sampleThunkConnect` is going to look like `(text: string) => Promise<ISampleThunkResponse>`, because dispatching a thunk returns what the thunk function returns. However, you're currently using the actual type of the thunk action creator itself, so that's causing the code to break.

The React-Redux typings for `connect` have some fancy internal types that "resolve the thunk" to its return type.  Per the examples in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/christianchown/05e084c78ec216070a5a2b80f0534d4b) and the post [Practical Typescript - React + Redux](https://dev.to/voronar/practical-typescript-react--redux-4enh), you can reuse one of those types to extract the types of the "props from `connect`", and let TS figure out the details itself.

Also, I strongly encourage you to use the ["object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object), rather than writing it as a function yourself.

Comment: Looking at the gist you provided, it's like the pattern I need to adopt is, pretty much upside down. I think my way of writing my React component is outdated. In the gist they create the `connector`, then, use it to decorate the component. Hopefully doing this won't have any effect on my code. I'll give it a try. As a side note you've also suggested using the object shorthand for mapDispatch, so that seems outdated in my code as well. I will upvote your comment, do some refactoring, and come back to give you the check if it all works out, with a sample. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I have refactored my code, updated the question, and closed it as it has resolved the issue! Thank you Mark!

Comment: Hey, I have a quick follow up question, so everything is working fine, except the cases where I need to pass a connected action creator into a child component as a prop. So I connect parent with 3-4 action creators, but one of the child components only needs `doFetchAppConnected` for example. How do I type this, in my child component props? I can't simply do `doFetchAppConnected: <typeof doFetchApp>;`, because of the original problem. Is there a way around this? Something like `ReturnType<DispatchMappedActionCreator<typeof doFetchApp>>`?

Comment: Ok figured it out, here is how you do it:

`import { InferThunkActionCreatorType } from 'react-redux';`

`export type IDoFetchApp = InferThunkActionCreatorType<typeof doFetchApp>;`

`doFetchAppConnected: IDoFetchApp;`